# TypeScript sets type 'never' for resolved value after Promise.allSettled().forEach() processing

Tags: typescript, foreach, promise, type-inference, typescript-never

TypeScript is giving me a type 'never' after a Promise.allSettled(promises).forEach(results)?

```
type myValue = {
        test1: string;
        test2: string;
        test3: string;
    } | undefined;


const go = async () => {

    // the values
    let value: myValue = undefined;
    let value2: myValue = undefined;

    // do some async requests
    const results = await Promise.allSettled([
        Promise.resolve({test1: 'test1.1', test2: 'test2.1', test3: 'test3.1'}),
        Promise.resolve({test1: 'test1.2', test2: 'test2.2', test3: 'test3.2'}),
    ]);

    // process results
    results.forEach( (result, index) => {
        if( result.status === "fulfilled") {
            if( index === 0 ) {
                // set value
                value = result.value;
            }
            if( index === 1 ) {
                // set value
                value2 = result.value;
            }
        }
        if( result.status === "rejected") {
            // process error
            console.error("error", result.reason);
        }
    });

    // checking if value is set
    if( !value || !value2 ) {
        throw new Error("no Value found");
    }

    // with TypeScript errors
    console.log("the type given is 'never', but value.test1 is set:", value.test1);
    console.log("the type given is 'never', but value2.test3 is set:", value2.test3);
}

go();
```

TS playground: [Visit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFlwDUCGAbArnAvLA3sLEcUaNAM6gCMAXLJQE4CWAdgOYDchJxZlATHUatO3HrD6gAzENDN2XEgF9YAH1gYWAE2gAzVtC1cQAYwD2LSrDZnYuFOXAsTsABQBKOwD58IEgHp-CQALOAA3dCxyMVg0aFBYCMxoOkRUZLsNbT0DIxi4hKSsQQRkSJwsnX0WQ2MAoK1bcjMAWzgHJxcGaABHKNBoknNLBO7yDDQBzJQAdxQmBIAFBlamcmgAOnQ0AGV40DitVwBtGJJl1fWNsbM0MOhXPElaWAByZ42qV4AaCQpQErvf78T4-P6UGRvSRSUFKdzfM7EC4tNabG53B5Pf4vIGUKgbfhgySA4kEon-SG46RkuEIkgAXXcdWIgVgkBWJgo5FgYwmAxivMm5A2ujMDAAoigTMFXG5BaBfqwdAAPTzYHwEcREJi6WXyjaUFCgDDc7Bm2AAIl0E30aEOFs8mq1JB1sqV0GVdnNAAZYI7Ec6iKz1oVygHA0UKvrI4pA0QlOGXbrYO7PWbcFQ-b44+Jg-FEmGczxI-xMtHyrG4wnndWta6eRQ+QbQEaTV7cBbugAraAmMhaB3ZnOs9lmTnkbnQBgrBiJ4jDZpxDZTmeuC0rsUW3767oOCxM8O1+MHmKs6W9gDWIhTugLGTW9HiMXrAEJI2p1G-yqX-c7QMEVhmWAaiA8VpzFNcWFsdIsFgUVNAHA9lBiU8ghmBZglgAAVKBoB2ExmEgBINwYQZ5wsRdNjQMw2DXf84AgGBrCYe4WBTblXhqe4GDBAAjDBQ2SDZnnYx9QBoLc7ywYTsSQ8jLFuKiaLo0IJFw5jWNEzjoG4viBKk6AQWhUSQwk34SxkiEDwTYAbA8YwQGAIA)

I have tried:

- comments: @ts-ignore / @ts-expect-error / etc but I don't want to do this, because I need a lot of them.
- typecasting: value = value as MyValue; will also make the error dissapear, but should not be needed here

Why is TypeScript not inferring the type here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, TypeScript "stores" the value of `value` and `value2` to be `undefined`, even though the type is `MyValue`. Since TypeScript thinks it's `undefined` and you don't reassign it *in that scope* TypeScript still thinks it's undefined when you perform the check `!value || !value2`. Because TypeScript thinks it's undefined, it deduces that this condition will always be true and thus `value` and `value2` below can "`never`" run. At least, that's what the compiler thinks.

Yes, you do actually reassign the values later, but the compiler just can't see that yet.

You actually have a very easy way to fix it - just remove the explicit initial value of `undefined`:

```
let value: MyValue;
let value2: MyValue;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFlwDUCGAbArnAvLA3sLEcUaNAM6gCMAXLJQE4CWAdgOYDchJxZlATHUatO3HrD6gAzENDN2XEgF9YAH1gYWAE2gAzVtC1cQAYwD2LSrDZnYuFOXAsTsABQBKOwD58IEgHp-CQALOAA3dCxyMVg0aFBYCMxoOkRUZMViOISkrEEEZEjoYwCgrVtyMwBbOAcnFwZoAEco0GiSc0sExvIMNDa7WBQAdxQmBIAFBmqmcmgAOnQ0AGV40DitVwBtGJIpmbn5nrM0MOhXPElaWAByK-mqG4AaCQpQfLu3-gfn18oZW6SKQ-JTuJ67Yj7KqzBbHU7nS5va6fShUeb8X6SD5Y9GYt4AlHSXGg8EkAC67hKxECsEg0xMFHIsB6fTaMRZ-XI810ZgYAFEUCZgq43BzQC9WDoAB6ebA+AjiIhMXQisXzSgoUAYJnYXWwABEuj6+jQG31ngVipIypFkugUrseoADLALRCrUQaXMckV3R7cjhmRRWfMA5kPbAlH7rSrYHaHbrcFRXb4I+IvfFEr60zwA-xBmqw9HiFGraXFTag71+urQJrtY7cPrGgAraAmMhac2ptM0ulmBnkJnQBjTBjFoidSpxeYjseufVz3n6l5qxoOCyUv3loigqmeoJC9sAaxEcd0WeScaZ3pilYAhAG1OpH0V826raBgtNhrAWNBfz5UdeQXFhbHSLBYB5TQuy3ZQYhiGlhnGYJYAAFSgaBlhMZhIASJcGHaYgpxOBY0DMNgFy-OAIBgawmDOFhr1uf8zgYX4ACMMB9ZJ5iuZjvRoFdLywPikTg4iLGnMiKKo0IJEw+jGOYm5WJHTjuJE6BviBAT4iEl48zE-4tyjYAbA8YwQGAIA)